# Does changing a Rasterizer State affect every object (model) on the screen?

Tags: directx11

Quick easy question. When setting a Rasterizer State (like for example wireframe).....does that affect every object (model) on the screen?

For example, let's pretend I have 2 cubes. I use:

```
devcon->RSSetState(pRSWireframe);
```

Will that affect all the objects on the screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will only affect objects rendered after the state is changed.